# Left side floating dock missing in Kali Linux and Tweak is not working

Tags: linux, unix, kali-linux

For the past few days in my kali linux machine, the home screen is appearing entirely blank. All the files that were save there is not showing and the floating dock is not appearing like before when i move my cursor to the left. I searched stackexchange and saw that I have to modify some settings in tweak. But I cannot change a thing is tweak. Here is how it appears.

[image: This is my home screen, completely blank]

and this is how the extension region of Tweak appears.

[image]

Please help, what to do. As I am having a lot of problems due to the dock missing from the side, and all the desktop icons removed. (though i can access them via files).

Comment: Reasons for down vote should be appreciated rather than just using the downvote button as a key to express your daily frustration. Thank you. :)

Comment: The reason is that your question is not related to programming. It could be more appropriate for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for letting me know. Its a request to all please cite the reason for down vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tweaks program, turn the following extensions on: `Dash to dock`, `Desktop icons`.

Dash to dock is the left sidebar.

Desktop icons extension shows the files on the desktop.

Comment: See the image of tweak extension that I have added, see that I am not able to select anything from there.

Comment: There is a slider next to the minimize button. That slider now indicates that the extensions are disabled. Click it once to re-enable it. Then it will be able to function normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. <3 
It worked. Do u have any knowledge how on earth the settings changed?

Comment: It seems that some frustrated thugs disliked your answer as well as my question, without citing any reason. But still your answer helped me. Thank u.

Comment: @Turing101 I am glad to have helped you